# How to get the last value in a column which includes formulas in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, filter, max

Trying to return the last value in a column, regardless if we're talking numbers or letters. I had this ready to work;

```
=INDEX(FILTER(Indirect(A2&"!F4:F");(Indirect(A2&"!F4:F")<>””);AANTALARG(FILTER(Indirect(A2&"!F4:F");(Indirect(A2&"!F4:F")<>””)))))
```

It finds the name in A2 as a tab, and then finds the last statement at [name]!F4:F. The problem with this seems to be that there is an if-statement inside of F4:F, which is why it always returns blank. I tried to get a filter in between but that just doesn't seem to work. Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(A2&"!F"&MAX((INDIRECT(A2&"!F:F")<>"")*(ROW(INDIRECT(A2&"!F:F"))))))
```